# Javascript equality weirdness

Tags: javascript, jquery, equality

I'm trying to fetch some data through ajax. One of the data determines whether or not a checkbox should be checked by default. If the returned variable `isVisible` is `1`, then it should be checked, if its `0` then it should be unchecked. Here's the code:

```
$.getJSON(myUrl, function(result)
    {
        isVisible = result.isVisible;
        // snip...
    } );
```

Later on in the code:

```
var isChecked = (isVisible) ? true : false;
$("#visible").attr('checked', isChecked);
```

The problem is that, whether or not `isVisible` is set to 1 or 0, the `checked` variable is always being evaluated to true. I'm really not sure what the problem is. Perhaps `isVisible` is being treated as a string ?? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `isVisible` is a string. `"0"` is a truthy value in Javascript. Use this instead:

```
var checked = (isVisible==="1") ? true : false;
```

Comment: This is probably whats going on. I would also try doing typeof to see what type it is just to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
isVisible = (result.isVisible == "1")
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is asynchronous. you need to use callbacks.

```
$.getJSON(myUrl, function(result)
{
    isVisible = result.isVisible;
    // snip...
    callback_setvis();
} );

function callback_setvis(){
     var ischecked = (isVisible) ? true : false;
     $("#visible").attr('checked', ischecked);
}
```

---

After reviewing your question again it seems the above might not work.

This might be an issue of `attr` vs `prop`

if you are in jQuery 1.6 or greater you should do:

```
  $("#visible").prop('checked', ischecked);
```

Comment: that's what I'm doing. The value of `isVisible` is being set correctly, its `isChecked` which is evaluating to true no matter the value of `isVisible`

Answer (score 0):

I guess "isVisible" is a string not a number, so it pass the test.
Try parseint(isVisible, 10), an let me know